# Workflow status values show 18

Tags: 2010, workflow

I got this from [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/simonh/archive/2013/04/12/sharepoint-2010-workflow-status-values.aspx):

```
NotStarted = 0
FailedOnStart = 1
InProgress = 2
ErrorOccurred = 3
StoppedByUser = 4
Completed = 5
FailedOnStartRetrying = 6
ErrorOccurredRetrying = 7
ViewQueryOverflow = 8
Canceled = 15
Approved = 16
Rejected = 17
```

but in my workflow status column, it show value 18 which I have no idea whether my workflow is valid or not.

Do anyone have any idea on it?

Comment: Which sharepoint version are you using?

Comment: I'm using SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Hey guys, i think i just got the answer, i created another view for the list as standard view, then the workflow status column change from 18 to starting, originally I was set the list view as Datasheet view. =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i just got the answer, i created another view for the list as standard view, then the workflow status column change from 18 to starting, originally I was set the list view as Datasheet view. =D